# A question on multiplicative orders congruences

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p>2$ be a prime.

Do there exist arbitrarily large primes $q\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for which   the simultaneous congruences 
$$a^{(q-1)/p} \equiv (a+1)^{(q-1)/p} \equiv 1 \pmod q$$
have no solutions $a\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: No.  If $q$ is large enough, then there will be about $(q-1)/p^2$ residue classes $a \pmod q$ such that both $a$ and $a+1$ are $p$-th powers.  You  can see this most easily by using the characters of order $p$ to express the conditions that $a$ and $a+1$ are both $p$-th powers.  Then use the fact that Jacobi sums have size $\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer dealing perfectly with my question. Can you give me a reference book I should have in my library for this kind of subject. Sincerely

Comment: Take a look at Ireland and Rosen's Classical Introduction to Modern number theory.  They will cover Jacobi sums and also discuss a beautiful paper of Weil on solutions to diagonal hypersurfaces.  Your problem fits that framework well.